# ¿Como seleccionar 1 campo fecha con 3 etiquetas en SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

Estoy realizando un `query` en `oracle 11g` y me piden que seleccione las 3 últimas fechas en que un cliente pagó factura. El query lo tengo así:

```
    SELECT 
    t1.datefield date_1,
    t1.datefield date_2,
    t1.datefield date_3
FROM
    table t1
WHERE
    t1.datefield BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
    AND TO_DATE('31/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Necesito que mes_1 sea desde 1 julio hasta 31 julio, mes_2 desde 1 agosto hasta 31 agosto y mes_3 desde 1 septiembre hasta 30 septiembre...

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esa duda?

Comment: El resultado deseado no es muy claro. ¿Puedes incluir una muestra de tus datos, y el resultado deseado basado en esa muestra? Lo que pasa, es que hablas de 3 ultimas fechas, pero luego hablas de 3 meses distintos, y tu consulta menciona `date_n`... no es claro como las 3 cosas encajan juntas.

Comment: O sea, una fecha por mes, pero debe ser la ultima fecha para ese mes?

Comment: no, osea, que muestre las 3 ultimas fechas en que el cliente pagó factura, pero resulta que esa tabla factura solo tiene un campo de fecha.
 Necesito un resultado como este
<img src="http://s22.postimg.org/vmff7lioh/fechas.png">

Comment: y que tiene que ver con los meses? Que tal si las ultimas 3 fechas caen todas en el mismo mes? O es que eso no es posible? Y los meses tienen que ser siempre julio a septiembre? O simplemente los ultimos 3 meses a partir de hoy?  Para ti esto esta claro, pero para mi no tanto. Por eso, una muestra de tus datos con el resultado deseado es lo ideal. Si modificas tu pregunta es mas facil y mas apropiado que tratar de comunicarlo por medio de comentarios.

Comment: Los meses son solo un título para el campo, la gerencia los está pidiendo así

Comment: si es un poco complejo de entender, hasta donde entiendo @GioV quiere sacar los últimos 3 registros por mes, y agruparlos en columnas por mes. si el resultado que deseas es como la imagen que pusiste, entonces mi 2da opción sugerida debe ayudarte. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55ebd/11

Comment: @Ed Garcia: no es muy claro. Y segun la imagen, no parece ser el caso. Pero tal vez. GioV: es eso?  O es simplemente las ultimas 3 fechas presentadas 1 por mes en una fila?  ...y tal vez funciona asi porque se asume que cada mes solo puede tener una fecha? Nuevamente, una muestra de tus datos sería sumamente util para entender mejor.

Comment: eso es lo que está pidiendo la gerente, y no hallo forma de que se haga la consulta de esas fechas en una misma fila... pongamoslo así, estamos en octubre, y quieren que busque las 3 ultimas fechas en que un cliente facturó un servicio antes del mes actual, en ese caso serían julio, agosto y septiembre, entonces en mes_1 debo colocar una fecha correspondiente al mes de julio, mes_2 una fecha del mes de agosto y mes_3 una fecha de septiembre.

Comment: es posible que haya mas de una fecha por mes? Si es el caso, que sucede entonces?

Comment: No, el sistema no permite más de un pago del cliente al mes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que entiendo es que quieres las últimas 3 fechas en una sola fila (no me complico con la lógica de los meses, ya que parece que no importa en realidad). De ser así, esta consulta debería funcionar. No necesitas hacer joins:

```
select max(case when rn = 3 then datefield end) as mes_1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then datefield end) as mes_2,
       max(case when rn = 1 then datefield end) as mes_3
  from (select t.datefield,
               row_number() over (order by t.datefield desc) as rn
          from tbl t)
 where rn <= 3
```

Comment: ¡EEEESA ES LA QUE NECESITABA! ¡GRACIAS!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es usar la función de [row_number()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm), en este caso la lista va en [filas](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55ebd/1)

```
  SELECT datefield from(
   SELECT 
   datefield,
   row_number() 
   over(partition by TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(datefield,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'MM') order by datefield desc ) as rn
   from tabla1)
   where rn <=3)
```

En caso dado de que lo requieras en [columnas](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55ebd/11) puedes usar la clausula [With](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause):

```
WITH tabla AS
  ( SELECT 
           TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(datefield,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'MM') AS idFecha,
           datefield,
           row_number() over(partition BY TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(datefield,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'MM')
                             ORDER BY datefield DESC) AS rn
   FROM tabla1)
SELECT t1.datefield fecha1,
       t2.datefield fecha2,
       t3.datefield fecha3
FROM tabla t1
inner join tabla t2 on (t2.idFecha>t1.idFecha and t2.rn=t1.rn)
inner join tabla t3 on (t3.idFecha>t2.idFecha and t3.rn=t1.rn)
WHERE /*t1.idFecha=7*/ /*fecha del mes*/
  t1.rn<=1; /*Considera este número como la cantidad de registros por mes que quieres sacar*/
```

Comment: con tabla t2 y tabla t3 te refieres a misma tabla con diferentes etiquetas?

Comment: si, si te fijas a la tabla1 la meti a una tabla temporal llamada tabla y de ahí hago los joins, en la respuesta anexé unos sqlfiddles para que te sea más visual...a la tabla temporal (tabla) le cree un campo de número de fecha y ya con ese lo filtro en los inner joins hacia la misma tabla.

Comment: muy bien, haré la prueba, gracias.

Comment: Hice una corrección en el query, modifiqué los joins así independientemente del mes, va seleccionar los últimos 3...